# Flutter scroll brincado

Tags: flutter, scroll

En todas las partes donde tengo un ListView, ListView.builder o SingleChildScrollView, el ScrollController con solo deslizar poco brinca del inicio al fondo y viceversa.
[Video del problema](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IVtjKgPCQEw_g15ijdFEaAmJlPlAvLZY/view?usp=share_link)

Tengo otro proyecto, y no sufre de lo mismo.

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.12, on macOS 13.3.1 22E772610a darwin-arm64, locale es-419)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.77.3)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Aqui un ejemplo:
donde los itemDrawer son ListTitle:

```
ListView(
              controller: scrollDrawer,
              children: <Widget>[
                
                itemDrawer(
                    principal,
                    AppLocalizations.of(context).menuD_Supremo,
                    _supremo,
                    Icons.whatshot,
                    24),
                itemDrawer(principal, AppLocalizations.of(context).migracion,
                    _migracion, Icons.cloud_upload, 34),
                itemDrawer(
                    principal,
                    AppLocalizations.of(context).menuD_Incognito,
                    _accesoGimnasio && tutorial,
                    Icons.supervised_user_circle,
                    27),
            
              ],
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Si estás usando un proyecto viejo de Flutter, migra a un nuevo, usa esa estructura y sobre eso pega tu código.

Si es un proyecto nuevo, pero incluye Google Maps, he ahí el problema, revisa esto :  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/79641

La solución es arrancar el simulador con Roseta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73949295/666221

```
arch -x86_64 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator
```

Comment: GRACIAS, entiendo el problema, pero las soluciones propuestas, ya no funcionan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75535134/ios-simulator-scrolling-issue-without-rosetta-option-on-mac-m1

Comment: ninguna te funcionó?  a mi me funciona : arch -x86_64 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator

Comment: Y no, busque la opción pero ya no la dan para correr con Rosetta